# How to expose Odoo container to LAN

Tags: python, django, docker, odoo

I am currently trying to run a docker Odoo container and expose it to my local network so my team can start testing it out, but I can't access the container from another computer on the same network. How can I host odoo on a windows docker machine that will let my co-workers access and work with Odoo?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to expose the port that your odoo web service is running at. [From the official Odoo docker hub repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/):

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
```

Or without `docker-compose` you could use e.g.

```
docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo -- --db-filter=odoo_db_.*
```

If you want to access the internal port `8069` from external port `80`, you can simply change to port mapping to `80:8069`.

Afterwards odoo can be accessed with a browser at `[your-ip]:8069` or simply `[your-ip]` if you map the external port to 80.